# The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3a_API_28 was killed

Tags: android, android-emulator

I found the problem after upgrade Android Studio to version 4.1.3

I can't start the emulator even create new one. I get the error:

> The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3a_API_28 was killed.

I already try to reinstalling Intel HAXM, but no luck.
The strange one is initial size of my emulators are same.

[image]

When I ran the command `./emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_29`

I get:

```
emulator: Android emulator version 30.5.3.0 (build_id 7196367) (CL:N/A)
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOUSBHost.framework/Versions/A/IOUSBHost
  Referenced from: /Users/fanjavaid/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes same problem after updating:

- BigSur11.3
- Android Studio 4.1.3
- Android Emulator 30.5.5
- HAXM 7.6.5

[image]

```
➜  ~ emulator -avd Pixel_3_XL_API_30
emulator: Android emulator version 30.5.5.0 (build_id 7285888) (CL:N/A)
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
cannot add library /Users/student/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
added library /Users/student/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib
HVF error: HV_ERROR
qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize HVF: Invalid argument
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
qemu-system-x86_64: Back to HAX accelerator
emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:301: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
```

Comment: Updating to Android Emulator 3.5.6 should fix this now.